# Will the SuperMicro X7DCA-L take Fully Buffered memory?

Tags: memory, motherboard, ddr2, supermicro

I have a lot of Fully Buffered DDR2 memory http://www.hynix.com/datasheet/spd/HYMP351F72AMP4N3_SPD.pdf

My question is, would it work on SuperMicro X7DCA-L motherboard or do I have to purchase un-buffered memory ?

Motherboard specs: up to 48GB 667/533MHZ DDR2 ECC Register SDRAM
http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon1333/5100/X7DCA-L.cfm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of different memory techniques on the market. Some of these are:

1. SDRAM.
2. DDR (1)
3. DDR2
4. FB-RAM
5. DDR3

Things like SDRAM, DDR (1,2,3,...) come of two flavours: buffered (aka registered) or unbuffered (aka unregistered).

You specified "DDR2 ECC Register SDRAM" and "**Fully** Buffered" (FB-RAM). These two are quite different and not compatible. Therefor it will not work.

Answer (score -1):

No, it won't work.
You need to buy a Supermicro X7DWU motherboard.
http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon1333/5400/X7DWU.cfm
"Up to 64GB DDR2 800 / 667 / 533 SDRAM Fully Buffered DIMM (FB-DIMM) 1.8V or 1.5V supported"